# Quadrupole moment of 3- state in 208Pb?

Tags: nuclear-physics

$^{208}$Pb is a spherical nucleus, so its transition to the first 3$^-$ state is an octupole vibration. Why does this state then have an associated quadrupole moment, as mentioned by several authors?
E.g. [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269368901755) and [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269371902292) article.

Attaching two more articles, check [this one](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.38.807) and [this one](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269383900679)

Answer (score 1):

The *ground state* of Pb-208 is spherical (with spin-parity $0^+$, and [doubly-magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28physics%29) proton and neutron numbers).  However there is nothing that says that its *excited states* must also be spherical.  An octupole vibration may include dipole and quadrupole terms.

Edited: in the spirit of [this related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/244110/44126), a "rotational band" of states with spin-parity $\cdots \to 7^- \to 5^- \to 3^-$ could provide evidence of a nonzero moment of inertia (mass quadrupole moment) for whatever configuration of nucleons makes up the $3^-$ state.  I haven't checked whether that sequence exists or whether that's the method used in the papers you cite, however.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What the article say is that the vibration is purely octupolar, but after excitation, there exists a quadrupolar reorientation among the substates. I am not able to comprehend that.

Comment: Can you find me an open-access paper? My library doesn't have Physics Letters B going back that far.

Comment: I couldn't locate an open access article for this problem. Attaching two other articles in the question above, see if there are accessible.